# DotNetOpenAuth and LinkedIn

Tags: .net, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

Is it possible to use `DNOA` with LinkedIn ?

I need a way to retrieve data from LinkedIn based on a single user. This means, my application will have a single user that serves all requests. Is there a programmatic way to get authenticated with LinkedIn without the need to redirect the user to LinkedIn page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All LinkedIn API calls need to have an authenticated user. They need to explicitly grant you their consent to make calls on their behalf.